# Hibernate Table Not Mapped Even though its mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Im Building an hibernate application.But while running the application getting the following error.Checked in stackoverflow but the issue is not resolved.Can someone guide me on this

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ReferenceType is not mapped [ from ReferenceType fret]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.generateQueryException(QuerySyntaxException.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894)
    at com.subex.rocfm.hibernateutil.GenericDAOImpl.findAll(GenericDAOImpl.java:182)
    at com.subex.rocfm.hibernateutil.testing.getAllReferenceTypes(testing.java:25)
    at com.subex.rocfm.hibernateutil.testing.main(testing.java:42)
```

Please find the hibenate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
  "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:db</property>
    <property name="connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    
    <mapping class="com.subex.rocfm.anirudh.ReferenceType"/>
    <mapping class="com.subex.rocfm.anirudh.RecConf"/>
    
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Please find the POJO Class for referencetype

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unused"})
@javax.persistence.Entity
@javax.persistence.Table( name = "reference_type" )
@com.subex.spark.database.annotation.Table( indexes = { 
    @com.subex.spark.database.annotation.Index( name = "reference_type_pk", columnNames = { "fret_id" }, unique = true, businessConstraint = true, displayName = false )
}, prefix = "fret" )
@org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDefs( {
    @org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef( name = "partitionFilter", parameters = @org.hibernate.annotations.ParamDef(name = "partitionIds", type = "int")),
    @org.hibernate.annotations.FilterDef( name = "deletedFilter", parameters = @org.hibernate.annotations.ParamDef(name = "deleteFl", type = "yes_no"))
} )
@org.hibernate.annotations.Filters( {
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Filter( name = "partitionFilter", condition = "ptn_id in ( :partitionIds )" ),
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Filter( name = "deletedFilter", condition = "fret_delete_fl = :deleteFl" )
} )
public class ReferenceType extends AbstractHibernateObject
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private RecConf recConf = null;
    private Integer frecId = null;
    private String fretDescription = null;

    public ReferenceType()
    {
        this( false ); 
    }

    public ReferenceType(boolean generateId)
    {
        super( generateId ); 
    }

    @javax.persistence.Id
    @javax.persistence.Column( name = "fret_id" )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type( type = "int" )
    @javax.validation.constraints.Min( 1 )
    public long getFretId() { return  getId(); }
    public void setFretId( long id ) { setId( id ); }

    @javax.persistence.Version
    @javax.persistence.Column( name = "fret_version_id" )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type( type = "int" )
    public int getVersionId() { return super.getVersionId(); }

    @javax.persistence.Basic
    @javax.persistence.Column( name = "fret_delete_fl" )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type( type = "yes_no" )
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    public Boolean getDeleteFl() { return super.getDeleteFl(); }

    @javax.persistence.Basic
    @javax.persistence.Column( name = "system_generated_fl" )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type( type = "yes_no" )
    public Boolean getSystemGeneratedFl() { return super.getSystemGeneratedFl(); }

    @javax.persistence.Basic
    @javax.persistence.Column( name = "ptn_id" )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type( type = "int" )
    @javax.validation.constraints.Min( 0 )
    public int getPartitionId() { return super.getPartitionId(); }

    @javax.persistence.ManyToOne( fetch = javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY )
    @javax.persistence.JoinColumn( name = "frec_id", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true )
    @NotFound( action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE )
    public RecConf getRecConf() { return recConf; }
    public void setRecConf( RecConf val ) { this.recConf = val; }


    @javax.persistence.Basic
    @javax.persistence.Column( name = "frec_id", nullable = true, insertable = false, updatable = false )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type( type = "int" )
    public Integer getFrecId() { return this.frecId; }
    public void setFrecId( Integer val ) {this.frecId = val; }

    @javax.persistence.Basic
    @javax.persistence.Column( name = "fret_description", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type( type = "String" )
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    @org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty
    @org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length( max = 4000 )
    public String getFretDescription() { return this.fretDescription; }
    public void setFretDescription( String val ) {this.fretDescription = val; }
```

Find the method from which fires the query

```
    public static List<ReferenceType> getAllReferenceTypes()
    {
        String query = " from ReferenceType fret";
        List<ReferenceType> list = null;
        
        ReferenceTypeHelper rth = new ReferenceTypeHelper();
        
        try {
            list = rth.findAll(query);
            System.out.println("List::::::::::"+list);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return list;
    
    }
```

This is where i'm creating an hibernate session

```
public class HibernateUtil
{
    public static Class< ? >[] schemas = new Class[]
    {};

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( HibernateUtil.class );

    public static String hibernateFileName = "/hibernate.cfg.xml";

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
    {
        try
        {
            Configuration config = new Configuration().configure( hibernateFileName ); //COMMENT_FOR_ROC3

            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings( config.getProperties() ).build(); //COMMENT_FOR_ROC3

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory( serviceRegistry ); //COMMENT_FOR_ROC3


            return sessionFactory;
        }
        catch ( Exception ex )
        {
            logger.error( "SessionFactory creation failed.",ex );
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError( ex );
        }
    }


    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        if ( sessionFactory != null )
        {
            return sessionFactory;
        }
        synchronized (HibernateUtil.class)
        {
            if ( sessionFactory == null )
            {
                sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static Session getSession()
    {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        return session;
    }

    public static void commitTransaction( Session session )
    {
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public static void shutdown()
    {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

Abstract Hibernate Object looks like this

```
public abstract class AbstractHibernateObject implements Serializable
{

    public AbstractHibernateObject()
    {

    }

    public AbstractHibernateObject( boolean generateId )
    {
        if ( generateId )
        {
            generateId();
        }
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id = -1L;

    private int intId = -1;

    private int versionId = 1;

    private Boolean deleteFl = false;

    private Boolean systemGeneratedFl = false;

    private int partitionId = -1;

    private int userId = -1;

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId( Long id )
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getIntId()
    {
        return intId;
    }

    public void setIntId( int intId )
    {
        this.intId = intId;
    }

    public int getVersionId()
    {
        return versionId;
    }

    public void setVersionId( int versionId )
    {
        this.versionId = versionId;
    }

    public Boolean getDeleteFl()
    {
        return deleteFl;
    }

    public void setDeleteFl( Boolean deleteFl )
    {
        this.deleteFl = deleteFl;
    }

    public Boolean getSystemGeneratedFl()
    {
        return systemGeneratedFl;
    }

    public void setSystemGeneratedFl( Boolean systemGeneratedFl )
    {
        this.systemGeneratedFl = systemGeneratedFl;
    }

    public int getPartitionId()
    {
        return partitionId;
    }

    public void setPartitionId( int partitionId )
    {
        this.partitionId = partitionId;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        // Return the class name and the primary key
        return this.getClass().toString() + " - " + getId();
    }

    public final boolean equals( Object other )
    {
        // Check for reference equality
        if ( this == other )
        {
            return true;
        }

        if ( other == null )
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Check the type is the same (this also checks for null)
        if ( !( other instanceof AbstractHibernateObject ) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        if ( !getClass().isInstance( other ) && !other.getClass().isInstance( this ) )
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Check only the primary keys
        AbstractHibernateObject otherHibernateObject = ( AbstractHibernateObject ) other;
        return this.getId() == otherHibernateObject.getId();
    }

    public final int hashCode()
    {
        // Base the hashcode on the primary key
        return ( int ) getId().intValue();
    }

    public void generateId()
    {
        HibernateIntegerPrimaryKeyAttacher keyHelper = new HibernateIntegerPrimaryKeyAttacher();
        keyHelper.generateKey( this );
    }

    public int getUserId()
    {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId( int userId )
    {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the part where you are creating the `SessionFactory`?

Comment: @crizzis I've edited the above post..could you please check it.

Comment: How your `AbstractHibernateObject` object look like? and Why you are supressing `unused` warning, is this object not used anywhere?

Comment: @code_mechanic I have added the code for ```AbstractHibernateObject```

Comment: It is very hard to tell what's going wrong with your code, it could be anything like package name, small issue in cfg or something else, I suggest you trim down everything and try out minimal code and prefer using annotation without package names,